# Can I make any mess if I'd connect to remote server via PuTTy in a wrong way?

Tags: windows, putty

I just start using a new hosting. After I registered and get IP and port number and I tried to connect to the server with PuTTy in its simple way:

- run PuTTy
- enter IP address and port number
- click Open button
- PuTTy showed me that the key pair was generated and I agreed

But after I enter my username and press Enter, unlike it was with other hostings, I've seen "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)".

After that I found the [step-by-step instruction](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/putty.htm) on a hosting site. But even after I have followed all the indicated steps I still have the same error.

Hosting technical support suggested me to add my IP address to allow list (I setup this list to allow any). That looked like a wrong approach to me but support insisted and I tried: result was a bit expectable: same error. Support still tries to face me into the instruction I have read already.

I think I need to reset the key pair I have generated in the very beginning. But I did not find any key for this server in the Windows registry.

What should I do to avoid this error and connect to the server?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21535907/1768141) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294381/google-server-putty-connect-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-a) might help

Comment: The server you are connecting to only supports publickey authentication (this is different to the putty key dialog you agreed to).  You need your own public/private keypair.  The public key is registered at the server end, and you prove it is yours with the private key to authenticate.  If you have instructions to follow, post a link.

Comment: If you're using Amazon EC2, [read this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html)

Comment: @Paul Oh! The link to the instruction disappeared while I moved this question from Stackoverflow. I updated the post and added necessary link.

Comment: @Vinayak I'm using SiteGround hosting. The first and third links you've suggested are related to Amazon AWS service so it's not goes for me. The second related to Google Compute Engine and has several general answers and several answers related to particular Google's service. But I didn't get any valueble information. Could you add any info based on the hoster name information?

Comment: Do you have the ppk file from this step: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/putty.htm

Comment: In addition to the link that @Paul posted, you may first need to [generate/retrieve your private key for SSH access from the server](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm)

Comment: Please include the *Event log* from PuTTY (right click on PuTTY window title) into your question (after you have followed all the instruction from your hosting provider). Ntb, the suggestion with IP allow list is nonsense (you have already connected, so this cannot be about IP blocking).